# Recurrence or multiple executions in rxjava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a specific task to get several packs of data from server by calling same request several times. While answers contains ***more*** flag - i have to recall this request.

It seems something like this:

```
fun getData(some params): Single<Response<DataEntity>>
//
repository.getData(params)
    .flatMap {
        if (it.body()?.more == false)
           more = false
        else (
          // here i want to repeat my request 
          // repository.getData(params) to get more data
        )
    }
    .flatMap {// here i want to get all the data from 
              //previous requests to save to db etc.
    }
```

Maybe i have to use something like *repeatWhen* or *repeautUntil* operators but i can't find the solution for now. Please help!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `concatMap` operator in a recursive way, and as exit condition return just the result:

```
Single<Response<DataEntity>> getDataAndContinue(params) {
  return getData(params)
      .concatMap(new Func1<Response<DataEntity>, Single<Response<DataEntity>>>() {

        @Override
        public Single<Response<DataEntity>> call(Response<DataEntity> response) {
          if (!response.body().hasMore()) {
            return Single.just(response);
          }
          return Single.just(response)
              .concatWith(getDataAndContinue(params));
        }   
    });
}
```